# I want to show the setFlash message for a longer period of time (20000 not 3000)

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am using the setFlash function to show a message at the top of the page, but I want to change how long it shows for (currently in the .js file it is on 3000, but I want it to show for 20 secs not 3)

Is there a way to code the time it stays on the page for a specific setFlash? rather than changing the website wide setFlash default?

This is the code I have in my controller page.

```
 $this->Session->setFlash(__l('There is not enough in escrow to close the project ') , 'default', null, 'error');
            $this->redirect(array(
                'controller' => 'escrow_accounts',
                'action' => 'add',
                'project' => $escrowAccount['Project']['id']
            ));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a custom template for flash message. For example:

```
// location /app/View/Elements/flash_message.ctp

<div id="flashMessage" data-timeout="<?php echo $timeout;?>"> 
    <?php echo $message; ?> 
</div>
```

Then use this custom template by setting Session flash message:

```
$this->Session->setFlash(
    __l('There is not enough in escrow to close the project '), 
    'flash_message', 
    array('timeout' => 3000), 'error');
```

Now, you need to take timeout param in javascript. I assume, you're using jQuery:

```
var interval = $("#flashMessage").attr("data-timeout");
```

And that's it, you can set custom timeout whatever you want.

Comment: I get the first two sections but the jQuery bit - how do I take out time param? just delete something? my js currently looks like this `$.fn.flashMsg = function() {
        $this = $(this);
        $alert = $this.parents('.js-flash-message');
        var alerttimer = window.setTimeout(function() {
            $alert.trigger('click');
        }, 3000);` So where do I add that last line you mentioned `var...` ?

Comment: Try this: 


    `$.fn.flashMsg = function() { 
     $this = $(this); 
     $alert = $this.parents('.js-flash-message'); 
     var interval = $("#flashMessage").attr("data-timeout");
     var alerttimer = window.setTimeout(function() { $alert.trigger('click'); }, interval);
    }`

Comment: But wouldn't this then mean I need to add the `array('timeout' => 20000), 'error');` to all of the `$this->Session->setFlash(` sections which do not currently have a timeout function set? or does it default somehow?

Comment: sorry what I mean is that I have other flash messages that use the `'error'` bit so if I change the code above then I would need to find all the other error flash messages which connect to `'error'` and add in that '20000' code you said about. How would I keep the original flash message popup for the original time and the new message to stay for the 20000?

Comment: I can't say I understood your question. If you want to use default - use your previous code. If you want to use custom timeout - use mine. Where is the problem? Or use my custom everywhere with timeout you want.

Answer (score 0):

Flash messages can have a 4th parameter, the 'key', which you can then use as a handle for css and js. Read up on it here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/sessions.html#creating-notification-messages

So, you'd have a key called 'long-flash' or similar, and just set those particular flash messages to show for 20 sec.

Answer (score 0):

Let me give an example where message pause is set: This will give you 30 seconds.

```
$this->flash('Your message', array('action' => 'index'), 30);
```

Comment: He's asking about the 'setFlash' method - not the 'flash' method. They're two different things. 'flash' is for redirection, which isn't what he wants.